# bash tty input drain (or flush?) (again)

Tags: bash, input, flush

I messed up my previous ask, dunno how to fix it, asked moderator to supress it.
I re-ask here my question in a simpler form more understandable.

How to drain any type ahead on the stdin before issuing a Query/Reply sequence to a terminal emulator from bash.

The demo below emulate a command loop in a script, read a user 'command', do this action (here a sleep) then 'would like' to query/reply the terminal emulator (here asking for term ID, but you can imagine any kind of query a terminal emulator would accept) so before the query/reply we must drain any type ahead. Here I attempted a read until empty.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
read -s -dc -p $'\e[0c' gr # The good query reply 

typeset -i i=0 n=30
while((i<n))
do
  read -p "cmd: "  c          # Read user command
  sleep 1                     # emulate user command that takes time
  echo "cmd '$c' done"
  while read -s -n 1 -t .1 a  # drain type ahead
  do [ "$a" = "" ] && break;
  done
  read -s -dc -p $'\e[0c' r  # emit a terminal query and read reply.
  [ "$r" != "$gr" ] && echo "Got corrupted reply '$r' '$gr'"
  ((i++))
done
```

When run it, at promp 'cmd:' enter a slowly, and wait for next prompt.

Using bash BASH_VERSION='4.4.19(1)-release' with both mate-terminal, or xterm I got this

```
TC$ ./t.sh
cmd: a
cmd 'a' done
cmd: a
cmd 'a' done
cmd: a
cmd 'a' done
cmd:
```

When typing a faster (not waiting the prompt) I then have some typeahead chars on the sdtin and I got this, despite my poorly attempt to drain the input.

```
TC$ ./t.sh
cmd: a
a
a
a
acmd 'a' done
Got corrupted reply 'a
a
a
md: 
a
a
cmd '' done
Got corrupted reply 'a
```

Any advise about how to drain the input in a in such bash application?
Cheers

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/276531/clear-stdin-before-reading no need for a loop if you set a huge number of characters to read, and with bash 4 you can set timeout to 0

Comment: Ha super thanx :) I din't spoted the superuser answer, and didn't thought setting a big -n would help but it does, the -t 0 don't help though (on my system) still getting bad input with it, so I keep -t .1, cheers